# "When he come we will eat" or "When he comes we will eat"

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Which is the right way to say it? In Spanish we use Present Subjunctive in this case (Cuando el venga comeremos), but I don't know in English.

Comment: _when he comes_ is correct. You should probably check out our sister site ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: *When he come* is correct Early Modern English, but, among speakers of Modern English, it will draw questioning gazes.

Comment: Which is to say, it went out of style around 1660 or so.

Answer (score 1):

The correct one would be the second one because the first one is not fully in the future tense. When you say come in the future tense it makes no sense a bit like viene or venir in Spanish.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, one can say in English the subjunctive is rare. In French, they use a lot of subjunctives, though in most cases there is no real necessity for a subjunctive. And I think that is true for Spanish as well.  In subordinate sentences with "when" (temporal) you never have a subjunctive in English. I guess the Spanish subjunctive after cuando is only used to show the subordination of the cuando-clause.

Comment: No, that is not how the subjunctive works. At all. Nor is it unnecessary as you continue to pretend. It is used in this instance in Spanish because the person hasn't gotten there yet, and therefore the indicative is wrong. The present indicative in both clauses would mean something utterly different.  PLEASE stop badmouthing Romance grammatical matters that you've no understanding of nor appreciation for.

Comment: @tchrist -I have studied French for five years at university and the French subjunctive even longer. I think I know of what I'm talking about and it has nothing to do with "badmouthing".

Comment: rogermue - The subjunctive present is Spanish here is absolutely necessary. And when you use "Cuando" like in this case you must use Subjuntivo Presente, there is no other way.

Comment: @marcela -I have no doubt that in Spanish a subjunctive is used but you can't tranfer every Spanish subjunctive into English.

Comment: I know that, I didn't say so. Did I? The Subj is use sometimes equal like English but most of the cases are used in different ways. I just was commenting about what you say that we could not use it in Spanish, but we have to use it, is obligatory in the example I gave. Your answered like you didn't understand my commentary.